# How to Find and compare Dates on Official MongoDB Go Driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I am new to mongodb-go-driver and i am stuck.

I have a date inside a struct like:

```
type Email struct {
    Date        string            `json:"date"`
}
```

the Dates on my mongoDB and mapped in my struct have the values like "02/10/2018 11:55:20".

I want to find on my DB the elements that Date are after an other date, i'm trying this but the response is always null.

```
initDate, _ := time.Parse("02012006", initialDate)
cursor, err := emails.Find(context.Background(), bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("date", bson.EC.DateTime("$gt", initDate.Unix()))))
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's a string, not a [date](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#DateTime).

Comment: @AlexBlex, How do i compare that two dates? i mean, if i parse a date to string i cannot compare them. Another way, how do i parse the string date to date?

Comment: It's stored as a string in the db, so the only comparison you can do is a string comparison, e.g. `02/10/2018 11:55:20`  will be less than `12/09/2018 11:55:20`. Starting from v4.0 there is an option to [convert string to date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/index.html#converting-to-a-date) in aggregation pipeline, but first of all it is extremely inefficient and it won't work with your date format. The short answer is you can't do that without changing all documents stored in the collection.

Answer (score 4):

> the Dates on my mongoDB and mapped in my struct have the values like "02/10/2018 11:55:20".

There are a number of ways you could do. The first, as mentioned on the comment, is to convert the `string` date into an actual date format. See also [MongoDB Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/). Storing date values in the proper date format is the recommended way for performance.

If you have a document:

```
{ "a": 1, "b": ISODate("2018-10-02T11:55:20Z") }
```

Using [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) (current v1.2.x) you can do as below to find and compare using date:

```
initDate, err := time.Parse("02/01/2006 15:04:05", "01/10/2018 11:55:20")
filter := bson.D{
    {"b", bson.D{
        {"$gt", initDate},
    }},
}
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), filter)
```

Please note the layout value in the example above for `time.Parse()`. It needs to match the string layout/format.

An alternative way, without converting the value is to use [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). You can use [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator to convert the `string` date into date then use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage to filter by date.

For example, given documents:

```
{ "a": 1, "b": "02/10/2018 11:55:20" }
{ "a": 2, "b": "04/10/2018 10:37:19" }
```

You can try:

```
// Add a new field called 'newdate' to store the converted date value
addFieldsStage := bson.D{
    {"$addFields", bson.D{
        {"newdate", bson.D{
            {"$dateFromString", bson.D{
                {"dateString", "$b"}, 
                {"format", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"},
            }},
        }},
    }},
}

initDate, err := time.Parse("02/01/2006 15:04:05", "02/10/2018 11:55:20")

// Filter the newly added field with the date
matchStage := bson.D{
    {"$match", bson.D{
        {"newdate", bson.D{
            {"$gt", initDate},
        }},
    }},
}
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{addFieldsStage, matchStage}

cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.Background(), pipeline)
```

Answer (score 1):

The unstable `bsonx` package in `mongodb-go-driver` has a `DateTime` Type.
You can add the field in your struct like this:

```golang
type Email struct {
    Date bsonx.Val
}
```

To declare the struct use `bsonx.DateTime(millis int64)`:

```golang
Email{
    Date: bsonx.DateTime(time.Now().UnixNano()/1e6)
}
```

*`time.Now().UnixNano()/1e6` basically gets the unix millis.

And you can convert it to `time.Time` with `email.Date.Time()`